# Why Twitter Bootstrap 2 btn-group doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any possibility to make it work? Here's my code (I'm using it in a table):

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('characters/{{ $player->name') }}">View</a></td>
    <td>{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('players.destroy', $player->id))) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger')) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}</td>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like you're splitting the buttons up with `<td>` elements.. can you put them all into one table cell (`<td>`)?

Comment: @msturdy Already tried that, they appear but not inline. pic: http://2.imgland.net/uAFIMw.png

Comment: make the cell wider!  :)

Comment: @msturdy Already tried something like `<td style="width: 40px;">..</td>` but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: hang on, the problem is also with the `<form>` element, will see if I can make up a jsfiddle to help

Comment: check that answer.. seems to work ok here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply give `class="btn-group"` to the `<form>` element:

Try something like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-mini btn-info" href="{{ URL::to('characters/{{ $player->name') }}">View</a>
        {{ Form::open(array('class' => 'btn-group', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('players.destroy', $player->id))) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger')) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</td>
```

your HTML at the end should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hyWnt/1/

---

**Updated jsfiddle for Bootstrap 2.3.2 : http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/HyfKZ/4/**

the changes are:

New CSS:

```
div.btn-group + form.btn-group {
    margin-left: -5px;
    display:inline;
}
```

And the code should then be:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('characters/'. $player->name) }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-info">View</a>
            <span class="btn" style="display:none"></span>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/account/management/characters/delete/23" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="btn-group">
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="7GKfarNh81RKu1Y5Dts8bYeFjOG7i8bLdD0CdNLa">        
            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
            <input class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete">            
        </form>    
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: OK.. so I'm missing something here, can you post more of your code please?  Preferably the part of the blade.php that generates the whole table.  did you see the jsfiddle?

Comment: @core_m updated the jsfiddle to have a more detailed example, with borders to make it easier to visualise the resulting HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/hyWnt/2/

Comment: here's my view: http://paste.laravel.com/Jti and my base view/master layout: http://paste.laravel.com/Jtj

Comment: Looks ok.. what's the resulting HTML of the page when you view it in the browser?

Comment: found out the view href doesn't work, I expected it to be working: `<a href="{{ URL::to('characters/ {{$player->name}}') }}">View</a>` Do you know how to solve it? Maybe it's causing the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35473/discussion-between-msturdy-and-core-m)

Comment: @core_m Updated above.. that should make things easier for you with the action.. let me know how you get on!

Comment: fixed some errors, adjusted margin-left to 0px, now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: I've also fixed the action, but whenever I click a View button it does take me to desired page, but with ? sign. like http://site.com/characters/test? 

form: http://paste.laravel.com/JuY

Comment: @core_m one more update above.. and check the jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/msturdy/HyfKZ/4/

Comment: Yep, works. Thanks. Is there any possibility to use the blade form?

Comment: yes of course, that HTML is what's generated by your calls to Form