# Bootstrap 3.3.1: Btn-group with RESTful Delete and Patch Buttons not connecting smoothly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, rest, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

While using Laravel and twitter bootstrap 3.3.1, I want to design a button group made up of two smoothly connected buttons, which look like that: [ Edit | Delete ]

Because of RESTful API and so on, I wanted to use routes based on at least a DELETE call. Therefore I need to put a POST or PATCH and a DELETE button together. Using blade syntax and form builder, it looks like that:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
       <a href="{{route('routeTo.edit', $param)}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
       </a>
       {!! Form::open(array('route' => array('routeTo.delete', $param), 'method' =>
                        'delete', 'class' => 'btn-group')) !!}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
       {!! Form::close() !!}
 </div>
</div>
```

But what appears is not a smoothly connected button-group, but a separated one, which also have a break line.

Also this Thread ( [Why Twitter Bootstrap 2 btn-group doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238756/why-twitter-bootstrap-2-btn-group-doesnt-work) ) tries to solve the problem in a earlier version, but their solution also doesn't work out for me.

Any thoughts and ideas how to combine POSTS and forms in a button-group? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btn-group` requires the child `btn` elements to be siblings, so all you'll need to do is:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('class' => 'btn-group', 'routeTo.delete',$param), 'method' =>'delete')) !!}
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group">
        <a href="{{route('routeTo.edit', $param)}}" class="btn btn-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also, the `type` attribute on an anchor is completely different to type on an input/button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How about combining a PATCH and a DELETE Button? So that are two distinct and independent forms, which are separated by a break-line again.

Comment: I'm assuming that you'd some input to go along with the PUT/PATCH form so it wouldn't work (unless you are going to be using javascript). This isn't really something that I've had to look into but another option might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020659/submit-form-using-a-button-outside-the-form-tag